# maven can't resolve dependency version, when i added spring framework BOM "Cannot resolve org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:unknown"

Tags: spring, maven, dependency-management

after i added spring-framework-bom, i removed version form all dependencies, but i got this error
*Cannot resolve org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:unknown
Cannot resolve org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:unknown*

**This my Pom.xml file** :

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MongoDB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!--mongodb-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot uses a plugin `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to resolve dependencies. If you want to use this plugin to resolve your dependencies, then you have to use `spring-boot`.

Add the `spring-boot-starter-parent` and the plugin in your `pom.xml`.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then the plugin will fetch the version of spring dependencies which are compatible with the spring boot version delclared in your `parent` tag.

But it will only resolve those dependencies which are related to spring. For example it will fetch compatible version of `spring-data-mongodb` but it will not fetch any verison of `org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver`. For `mongo-java-driver` you need to add the version specifically.

If you are not using `spring-boot`, then the best solution for you is to use specific `version`  for those dependencies.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.7</version>
        </dependency>
```